# ZEND form how to know the number of options of a dropdown input field

Tags: php, forms, zend-form

I have a dropdown input field (list of options populated from the database), is there a function that allows me to know the number of options?

```
echo $this->form->colors;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiselect

```
count($this->form->colors->getMultiOptions())
```

Comment: Was just about to post that :)

Comment: @vascowhite You're a better man than I b/c you cleaned up the question before posting an answer :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm very new to zend and I'm trying to learn how thing work.